# BUILDING LOGIN using ExtJS getView is not a function

Tags: extjs, extjs5

im trying to create a login using extjs with PHP but i stuck up to this problem...

```
TypeError: this.getView is not a function


this.getView().destroy();
```

here is my code....

i dont know why it could be error i just try to follow the tutorial in sencha docs

```
 buttons: [{
            text: 'Login',
            formBind: true,

        listeners: {
           click: function() {
                                        var form = Ext.getCmp('login').getForm();

                                        if(form.isValid()) {
                                                form.submit({
                                                        url : 'data/login.php',
                                                        method : 'POST',                                                      

                                                           success:function(){ 
                                                            this.getView().destroy();
                                                            Ext.widget('app-main');
                                                                },
                                                            failure: function() {
                                                                      obj = Ext.util.JSON.decode(response.responseText); 
                                                                        Ext.Msg.alert('Login Failed!', obj.errors); 
                                                            }
                                                });
                                        }
                               }              
        }
        }]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `console.log(this)`? I guess not...

`this` is always dependent on context. Your context here is not the view, but, if I am not mistaken, the Ext.Ajax.request, in whose `success` function you are trying to destroy the view.

This is why I refrain from using this in my code wherever it is not completely obvious even to a layman reader which context I am in.

EDIT: Since code looks bad in comments, I add it here.
The answer as per original Ext source would be

```
click: function() {
    var me = this;
    var form = Ext.getCmp('login').getForm();

    if(form.isValid()) {
        form.submit({
            url : 'data/login.php',
            method : 'POST',

            success:function(){ 
                me.getView().destroy();
                Ext.widget('app-main');
            },
            failure: function() {
                obj = Ext.util.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
                Ext.Msg.alert('Login Failed!', obj.errors);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

while I personally would use

```
click: function(btn) {
    var form = Ext.getCmp('login').getForm();

    if(form.isValid()) {
        form.submit({
            url : 'data/login.php',
            method : 'POST',

            success:function(){ 
                btn.up('window').hide();
                Ext.widget('app-main');
            },
            failure: function() {
                obj = Ext.util.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
                Ext.Msg.alert('Login Failed!', obj.errors);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi sir do you have any idea to solve or how  to achieve what i want to do im pretty stuck up to create a login and im just a begineer in extjs

Comment: THANKS SIR ! i tried the first one but i didnt work then i try the second one and it works ! thanks for ur time